Problems validating JWTs in ASP.NET API running in a container
I'm working on containerizing an ASP.NET Web API.  My project is in .NET 8, and the API works fine running both in Visual Studio and Azure.  I can launch up the API and call it with JWTs that I obtain from Entra, all with no problem.  I configure authorization on the API as follows:
// Add authentication services
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options);

        options.Authority = $"{builder.Configuration["AzureAd:Instance"]}{builder.Configuration["AzureAd:TenantId"]}/v2.0";

        // The valid audiences are both the Client ID(options.Audience) and api://{ClientID}
        options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidAudiences =
        [
            builder.Configuration["AzureAd:ClientId"], 
            $"api://{builder.Configuration["AzureAd:ClientId"]}",            
        ];

        // Valid issuers here:
        options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidIssuers =
        [
            $"https://sts.windows.net/{builder.Configuration["AzureAd:TenantId"]}/",
            $"{builder.Configuration["AzureAd:Instance"]}{builder.Configuration["AzureAd:TenantId"]}/",
            $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{builder.Configuration["AzureAd:TenantId"]}/v2.0"
        ];
    });

So far so good.  Then I tried to containerize it.  I used the Visual Studio tooling to add docker support, including a docker file, and after some experimentation, it would run and launch up.  I can call methods in the API that do NOT require Authorization.  However, when I attempt to call a method in a controller with the [Authorize] attribute, it breaks.  The response is a 401 Unauthorized, and the headers returned are:
content-length: 0 
 date: Tue,16 Apr 2024 19:17:36 GMT 
 server: Kestrel 
 www-authenticate: Bearer error="invalid_token",error_description="The signature key was not found" 

Note that this same code that, if I launch it up as an API running locally, runs fine.  Launch it in a container, doesn't work.
My current hypothesis is that, when the JWT validation code runs, it attempts to fetch the signing key from the Authority and fails.  It works when launched locally because outgoing requests for signing keys are allowed and work fine, but when it's running in a container, the container isn't allowing that outgoing request.
To test this, I added a method to a controller that does the following:
        var client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://www.microsoft.com/");
        var resp = await client.GetAsync(string.Empty);
        html = await resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

Just to see if the container can make any outgoing request, any at all.  It fails with the following error:
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
 ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid because of errors in the certificate chain: UntrustedRoot

I'm not sure how to resolve this.  I don't want to have to install a cert or a key in the container, because what if that cert changes?  That should be obtainable at runtime.
Is there a way to allow outgoing HTTP requests from container code that I'm missing?
Thanks,

were you able to fix this? If so, how?

Sadly, no.  If there's a solution, I wasn't able to find it, and we abandoned the project for the time being.

You could ingnore the certificate validation like follwoing;
var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
httpClientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (message, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) =>{return true;};
var client = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler));
...


That would be good for development/testing, but what happens when we go to production?  In production, we definitely want JWTs to be validated.

@AllanAlderman Well "untrusted root" means your container lack of the CA crt. I cannot reproduce when use official mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 as base image to call "microsoftwebsite". Do you use other images?
